# How to display multiple p5.js scripts in a HTML/CSS grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, p5.js

I have multiple p5.js scripts that all produce a canvas of 100x100. Let's say I have 9 and this is the code of each one:

```
var canvas_size = 200

function setup() {
  createCanvas(canvas_size, canvas_size);
  frameRate(300);
}

function draw() {
    background(random(255));
}
```

Now I want my index.html to show each of the 9 scripts in a grid (number of columns and rows fixed or even better responsive). I am playing with the most common CSS examples of grids with no luck actually.

Here's my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Sketch</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <script src="libraries/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-item"><script src="sketch1.js"></script></div>
      <div class="grid-item"><script src="sketch2.js"></script></div>
      <div class="grid-item"><script src="sketch3.js"></script></div>
      <div class="grid-item"><script src="sketch4.js"></script></div>
      <div class="grid-item"><script src="sketch5.js"></script></div>
      <div class="grid-item"><script src="sketch6.js"></script></div>
      <div class="grid-item"><script src="sketch7.js"></script></div>
      <div class="grid-item"><script src="sketch8.js"></script></div>
      <div class="grid-item"><script src="sketch9.js"></script></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and style.css:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of your sketches will need to be implemented in [instance mode](https://p5js.org/examples/instance-mode-instantiation.html). This method avoids declaring your `setup`, `draw` and other p5.js lifecycle functions in the global scope, which would result in conflicts between your different sketches.

Example:

```
// all p5.js functions should be called via the p object
let sketch = function(p) {
  let x = 100;
  let y = 100;

  p.setup = function() {
    p.createCanvas(700, 410);
  };

  p.draw = function() {
    p.background(0);
    p.fill(255);
    p.rect(x, y, 50, 50);
  };
};

let myp5 = new p5(sketch);
```

To make each of your sketches appear in a particular grid position you can either have each sketch specify a container div id. Or you can use `document.currentSketch.parentElement`:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Sketch</title>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div id="sketchContainer1" class="grid-item">
      <script>
        function sketch1(p) {
          p.setup = () => {
            p.createCanvas(200, 200);
            p.background('cyan');
          };
        }

        new p5(sketch1, "sketchContainer1");
      </script>
    </div>
    <div id="sketchContainer2" class="grid-item">
      <script>
        function sketch2(p) {
          p.setup = () => {
            p.createCanvas(200, 200);
            p.background('magenta');
          };
        }

        new p5(sketch2, "sketchContainer2");
      </script>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <script>
        function sketch3(p) {
          p.setup = () => {
            p.createCanvas(200, 200);
            p.background('yellow');
          };
        }

        new p5(sketch3, document.currentScript.parentElement);
      </script>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <script>
        function sketch4(p) {
          p.setup = () => {
            p.createCanvas(200, 200);
            p.background('black');
          };
        }

        new p5(sketch4, document.currentScript.parentElement);
      </script>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```