# Add p5 element to html div

Tags: html, css, p5.js

How would i add a p5 element to an html div? for example, i have a function which draws sine waves like this:

```
            let theta = 0.0; // Start angle at 0
            let amplitude = this.circlesArray[i].radius / 2; // Height of wave
            let period = this.circlesArray[i].rotationSpeed * 500; // How many pixels before the wave repeats
            let dx = (TWO_PI / period) * this.xspacing;

            theta += 0.02;

            // For every x value, calculate a y value with sine function
            let x = theta;
            for (let i = 0; i < this.yvalues.length; i++) {
                this.yvalues[i] = sin(x) * amplitude;
                x += dx;
            }

            stroke(255);
            beginShape();

            for (let x = 0; x < this.yvalues.length; x++) {
                curveVertex(x * this.xspacing / 10, height / 2 + this.yvalues[x])
            }
            endShape();
        }
```

this draws sine waves using the p5 `beginShape();`,`curveVertex();`, and `endShape();` functions, which together make a continuous line representing a sine wave. the problem is, I want to put these sine waves inside an html div, so that they can be dynamically spaced with a flex-box instead of with absolute positions. does anyone know how i should do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default p5.js draws to a single `<canvas>` element. You can control where in the DOM this `<canvas>` element is located by getting the `p5.Renderer` returned by `createCanvas` and calling its `parent` method:

```
function setup() {
  let c = createCanvas(200, 200);
  c.parent('id_of_div');
}
```

There is also a library for p5.js called [p5.js-svg](https://github.com/zenozeng/p5.js-svg) that makes it possible to generate an SVG file from a set of drawing instructions, which might also be useful in this scenario.

Note: if you want to have multiple p5.js created graphics at different points in the DOM then you will need to use ["instance mode"](https://p5js.org/examples/instance-mode-instance-container.html). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69855360/how-to-display-multiple-p5-js-scripts-in-a-html-css-grid/69867319#69867319) for more info.

Comment: do you know if it is possible to change the location of specific p5-drawn elements WITHOUT making new canvases for each of them?

Comment: No, p5.js elements are always going the drawn into either a canvas, or using the library I mentioned, an SVG element. So if you want to leverage DOM layout like flex-box that is going to be per-canvas.